# How do I use the Google URL Shortener API on Android?

Tags: android, google-url-shortener

After much fiddling with trying to import the libraries myself, I finally managed to find out that I can do so using the Google Plugin for Eclipse, [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup#Eclipse).

However, I seem to be unable to find any examples of how to actually use the API on Android, at least none that are compilable, as the classes required in those examples seem to not be resolvable by Eclipse, so I can only assume that these classes do not exist in the libraries that are imported by the Google Plugin for Eclipse for the URL Shortener API. The closest thing to an example I could find is [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/urlshortener-robots-appengine-sample/src/main/java/com/google/api/client/sample/urlshortener/appengine/robots/UrlShortenerSample.java?repo=samples), which appears to be for Google App Engine, not Android, and uses classes that I cannot seem to get access to.

So the question is, how do I use this API to get a shortened version of a URL, in an Android application? Preferably, I would like to do it using an API Key, instead of OAuth.

Answer (score 7):

First create a project on google console and enable url shortner api and get api key and the use the following Asynctask to get shortened url.

```
 public class newShortAsync extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String> {

        String longUrl="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18372672/how-do-i-use-the-google-url-shortener-api-on-android/20406915";
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
         }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            System.out.println("JSON RESP:" + s);
            String response=s;
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject=new JSONObject(response);
                id=jsonObject.getString("id");
                System.out.println("ID:"+id);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            BufferedReader reader;
            StringBuffer buffer;
            String res=null;
            String json = "{\"longUrl\": \""+longUrl+"\"}";
            try {
                URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/urlshortener/v1/url?key=YOUR_API_KEY");
                HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                con.setReadTimeout(40000);
                con.setConnectTimeout(40000);
                con.setRequestMethod("POST");
                con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
                OutputStream os = con.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                        new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));

                writer.write(json);
                writer.flush();
                writer.close();
                os.close();

                int status=con.getResponseCode();
                InputStream inputStream;
                if(status==HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
                inputStream=con.getInputStream();
                else
                    inputStream = con.getErrorStream();

                reader= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                buffer= new StringBuffer();

                String line="";
                while((line=reader.readLine())!=null)
                {
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                res= buffer.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return res;




        }
    }
```

and then just execute this asynctask you will get a json responce in which id is present which is nothing but shortened Url.

Comment: {"error":{"message":"Invalid Value","code":400,"errors":[{"message":"Invalid Value","domain":"global","location":"resource.longUrl","reason":"invalid","locationType":"parameter"}]}} help me!

Comment: Did you copy paste the same code and changed just LONGURL and APIKEY?

Answer (score 4):

1. add to your manifest in `application` node:

> ```
>  <meta-data
>          android:name="com.google.android.urlshortener.API_KEY"
>          android:value="{YOUR_API_KEY}"/>
> ```

2. add folowing libraries:

> google-api-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
>
> google-api-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar
>
> google-api-services-urlshortener-v1-rev22-1.17.0-rc.jar
>
> google-http-client-1.17.0-rc.jar
>
> google-http-client-android-1.17.0-rc.jar

3. method:

   ```
      String shorten(String longUrl){

      Urlshortener.Builder builder = new Urlshortener.Builder (AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(), AndroidJsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null);
      Urlshortener urlshortener = builder.build();

       com.google.api.services.urlshortener.model.Url url = new Url();
       url.setLongUrl(longUrl);
       try {
          url = urlshortener.url().insert(url).execute();
           return url.getId();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           return null;
      }
   }
   ```

Comment: I used this without adding anything to the manifest and it still worked.

Comment: Is there any way to long the url from short?

Comment: Instead of adding all this libraries, I am just sending a post request to get short url. It is working fine. Please suggest me which to use?

Comment: @PrashanthDebbadwar, can you please post your code here? I even don't know, where do you send a post request. May be it will be usefull for someone.

Comment: To anyone trying to implement this see Liu Ocean answer. If you set the key in the manifest it will quietly fail.

Answer (score 4):

Now the Google shorter api needs key to work. I tried set key in manifest but it's not working. Key should be set by function library.

```
Urlshortener.Builder builder = new Urlshortener.Builder (AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            AndroidJsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(), null);
    Urlshortener urlshortener = builder.build();

    com.google.api.services.urlshortener.model.Url url = new com.google.api.services.urlshortener.model.Url();
    url.setLongUrl(longUrl);
    try {
        Urlshortener.Url.Insert insert=urlshortener.url().insert(url);
        insert.setKey("Your API KEY");
        url = insert.execute();
        return url.getId();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LogUtil.e(TAG, Log.getStackTraceString(e));
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use gradle apparently

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-urlshortener:v1-rev47-1.22.0'
}
```

[Google Shortner java gradle documentation](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/urlshortener/v1)