# How to make Firebase Storage urls shorter?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console, google-url-shortener, url-shortener

I'm using Firebase Storage to store images for my app project. The image urls are stored in Firestore. The problem is that all those urls are huge. Sometimes in the Firebase Console it get double scroll bars because of that. Is there any way we can make them shorter? Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20406915/7791183

Comment: @RajatMittal Thanks for pointing me in that direction but according to [this](https://goo.gl/), *On March 30, 2018, we turned down support for goo.gl URL shortener*. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: Try this out. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/urlshortener/v1

Comment: @RajatMittal Thanks again, but that resource is also using `goo.gl` short URLs, which in short time will not work anymore.

Comment: That article was updated on 13 Feb'19. I don't know, what google is upto!

Answer (score 1):

Actually Firebase Dynamic Links would be a nice one solution for your situation.

You can make it runs following these instructions in this [article](https://medium.com/@vejmartin/3-free-ways-to-shorten-urls-with-firebase-c3e023b33083) from Medium, I have just implemented it in one of my Apps and it worked as expected.

I hope it helps you and everyone having the same issue.

Comment: What's a good alternative now that Firebase Dynamic Links got deprecated?